# Prove that X is a Hausdorff space if and only if the diagonal is a closed set in its product topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, product-space

So I was trying to do this,and asked my professor to tell me if it was correct, but he wouldn't look at my work, here is my attemp to a solution.

Proof:
Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal.
$$\implies:$$

Let $X$ be $\mathcal{T}_2$
Let x, y $\in$ X

If $x \neq y \implies x\times y \not \in \Delta$

Since X is Hausdorff there must be $U, V$ nb of $x, y$ that are disjoint.

So $x \times y \in U \times V \subset X \times X -\Delta$, since $U, V$ have no common elements, then $X\times X -\Delta$ is an open set in $X\times X$ and $\Delta$ is a closed set.

$$\Leftarrow: $$
Let $\Delta$ be a closed set in $X \times X$

Let $x\neq y$ such that $x,y \in X$

$\implies x \times y \in X-\Delta \in X \times X$

Then there must exist $U, V \subset X$ such that $x \times y \in U\times V \subset X \times X-\Delta$ and $U, V$ are disjoint for otherwise they'd be in $\Delta$ (or at least an element of them would be in $\Delta$).

$\implies X$ is $\mathcal{T}_2$

Proved in both directions, the proof is finished.

Can you tell me if this attemp is correct?

Comment: In the first part, you should start by taking an element $x\times y$ not in the diagonal, then say $x\ne y$. In the second part, you have a typos in the fourth line ($U, V$ are subsets, not elements, of $X$; and later "$X\times X$", not "$X$"). Other than this, it is fine.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidMitra, I've edited now.

Comment: The idea is good, and your reasoning is correct. But I don't like your way of writting, I think It could be improved a bit.

Comment: @Marcos thank you I'll try to get better.

Comment: I mean, in an exam most of teachers would mark this as perfect or maybe 9/10, but if you have to write something academic you'll have to polish your writting. Otherwise, keep up the good work!!!!

Comment: @Marcos Thank you for your comments, I'm not trying to do anything academic but to pass my topology 1 class, hehe. I'll take your advise, though.